# Coin change algorithm and pseudocode: Need clarification

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I'm trying to understand the coin change problem solution, but am having some difficulty.

At [the Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change), there is a pseudocode solution for the dynamic programming solution, shown below:

```
n = goal number
S = [S1, S2, S3 ... Sm]

function sequence(n, m)
   //initialize base cases

   for i = 0 to n
     for j = 0 to m
       table[i][j] = table[i-S[j]][j] + table[i][j-1]
```

This is a pretty standard `O(n^2)` algorithm that avoids recalculating the same answer multiple times by using a 2-D array.

My issue is two-fold:

1. How to define the base cases and incorporate them in `table[][]` as initial values
2. How to extract out the different sequences from the table

Regarding issue 1, there are three base cases with this algorithm:

- `if n==0, return 1`
- `if n < 0, return 0`
- `if n >= 1 && m <= 0, return 0`

How to incorporate them into `table[][]`, I am not sure.  Finally, I have no idea how to extract out the solution set from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement a dynamic programming algorithm in at least two different approaches. One is the top-down approach using memoization, the other is the bottom-up iterative approach.

For a beginner to dynamic programming, I would always recommend using the top-down approach first since this will help them understand the recurrence relationships in dynamic programming.

So in order to solve the coin changing problem, you've already understood what the recurrence relationship says:

```
table[i][j] = table[i-S[j]][j] + table[i][j-1]
```

Such a recurrence relationship is good but is not that well-defined since it doesn't have any boundary conditions. Therefore, we need to define boundary conditions in order to ensure the recurrence relationship could successfully terminate without going into an infinite loop.

So what will happen when we try to go down the recursive tree?

If we need to calculate `table[i][j]`, which means the number of approaches to change `i` using coins from type `0` to `j`, there are several corner cases we need to handle:

1) What if `j == 0`?

If `j == 0` we will try to solve the sub-problem `table(i,j-1)`, which is not a valid sub-problem. Therefore, one boundary condition is:

```
if(j==0) {
  if(i==0) table[i][j] = 1;
  else table[i][j] = 0;
}
```

2) What if `i - S[j] < 0`?

We also need to handle this boundary case and we know in such a condition we should either not try to solve this sub-problem or initialize `table(i-S[j],j) = 0` for all of these cases.

So in all, if we are going to implement this dynamic programming from a top-down memoization approach, we can do something like this:

```
int f(int i, int j) {
  if(calc[i][j]) return table[i][j];
  calc[i][j] = true;
  if(j==0) {
    if(i==0) return table[i][j]=1;
    else return table[i][j]=0;
  }
  if(i>=S[j])
    return table[i][j]=table[i-S[j][j]+table[i][j-1];
  else
    return table[i][j]=table[i][j-1];
}
```

In practice, it's also possible that we use the value of `table` arrays to help track whether this sub-problem has been calculated before (e.g. we can initialize a value of -1 means this sub-problem hasn't been calculated).

Hope the answer is clear. :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  Two points: where exactly does `calc` come from?  As a boolean conditional, where dies it ever set as false?  Secondly, as a 2-D array, how would I extract out the possible sequences?

Comment: @Jason: `calc` is a boolean type matrix which denotes whether this "subproblem" has been calculated before, if it does, then we don't need to recalculate it and we can just use the previous calculated result. That's the core of dynamic programming

Comment: @Jason: Extracting possible sequences is a totally different issue though, since the number of possibilities can be quite huge, but still you can use a vector<int> v[i][j] to track this, following similar relationships.